# Function can not allocate memory for a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I have a struct which is called "visitor" and I want to write function which allocates the memory for my pointer to this struct ...

this Codes works:

```
visitor *visitorPtr = NULL;
int visitorCounter = 0;
visitorPtr = realloc(visitorPtr, ((visitorCounter++) * sizeof(visitor)));
```

but now I wanted to put this functionality to a function

```
void getMoreSpace(void *ptr, unsigned int counter)
{
    counter++;
    ptr = realloc(ptr, counter * sizeof(visitor));

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error allocating memory! \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

//Call in MAIN:
getMoreSpace(visitorPtr, visitorCounter);
```

Unfortunately it seems not to work because I cant create data for this pointer and get this Error when I make that for that struct:
Exception thrown at 0x0FDAE559 (ucrtbased.dll) in My-C-Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: You understand the concepts: call-by-value and call-by-reference?

Comment: You modify a _local_ variable, not the caller's variable. So the caller cannot see the change. Lookup  call-by-value and call-by-reference as Sourav Gosh suggests.

Comment: call-by-reference means for me if after the function the var is still in the changed state

Comment: *call-by-reference means for me if after the function the var is still in the changed state*  And how does C pass variables...

Comment: generally always by value and if you use a pointer its by reference! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visitorPtr` is passed as value to `getMoreSpace` function. Thus any changes done to `ptr` within the function will not update the `vistorPtr` in main.

What you need is call the function by reference as below.

```
void getMoreSpace(void **ptr, unsigned int counter)
{
    counter++;
    *ptr = realloc(*ptr, counter * sizeof(visitor));

    if (*ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error allocating memory! \n");
    }
}
```

And from `main` you call as below.

```
getMoreSpace(&visitorPtr, visitorCounter);
if (visitorPtr)
   ...do stuff....
```

Comment: That looks good to me.